# CSS not displaying with empty div tag

Tags: html, css

I've been having a problem with an empty div HTML tag. I've added CSS to it but the style is not showing. I've tried adding &nbsp to it but that didn't do anything. Is there any other way to fix this problem? The CSS in question:

```
<style type="text/css">
div#mainbutton { width: 28px; height: 28px; border-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); border-width:     
5px; border-radius: 2px; }
</style>
```

The HTML:

```
<div id="mainbutton">&nbsp;</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just missing style of border, when you won't add `border-style` property, browser don't know what to do.

```
#mainbutton { 
    width: 28px;
    height: 28px; 
    border-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); 
    border-width:5px; 
    border-radius: 2px; 
    border-style: solid;
}​
```

As **Border-style** you can use follows: `solid, dotted, dashed, double, groove, ridge, inset, outset or none`.

[Here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-style.asp) you can read more about it.

Comment: If it doesnt work you can also try browser prefixes like
-moz-border-radius
-webkit-border-radius
-khtml-border-radius
-o-border-radius

Answer (score 3):

Just add `border:solid;`

```
   <style type="text/css"> 
    div#mainbutton {width:28px;height:28px;border:solid 5px rgb(0, 0, 0);border-radius: 2px; } 
    </style>
```

and use css shortcut like `border:solid 5px rgb(0,0,0)` is same as `border-style:solid;border-width:5px;border-color:rgb(0,0,0)`

Answer (score 0):

You need use border-style in the css .